# Shell Script to show multiple line after match

Tags: shell, unix, awk, grep, cat

I got this file

```
root:
    admin = true
    SYSTEM = "compat"
    registry = files
    account_locked = false
    su = true
    sugroups = system,security,sec_grp

daemon:
    admin = true
    expires = 0101000070
    account_locked = true

bin:
    admin = true
    expires = 0101000070
    account_locked = true
```

I want to print only specific user and its attribute by using shell script. I try to use `cat`, `grep` and `awk` but i cannot find the solution yet.

Any Idea?

I have tested all answer with my system (Solaris 9). It doesn't work at all. I'm not sure am i do something wrong?

Comment: where do you have this output from

Comment: I meant, which command produces the output?

Comment: `cat /etc/security/user` from AIX platform

Comment: I guess that there are tools on AIX designed to output values for a certain user only. But unfortunately I have no AIX by the hand for investigation

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick `sed` solution:

```
sed -ne '/^daemon:/,/^$/p' filename
```

Which includes the blank line at the end, but is short and memorable.

Another strategy is to repeat the stanza-level data on each line to make the result friendlier to line-oriented tools, e.g.

```
awk '/^[a-z]/ {user=$1} (NF>1) {$1=user$1; print}' filename
```

Which generates this output:

```
root:admin = true
root:SYSTEM = "compat"
root:registry = files
root:account_locked = false
root:su = true
root:sugroups = system,security,sec_grp
daemon:admin = true
daemon:expires = 0101000070
daemon:account_locked = true
bin:admin = true
bin:expires = 0101000070
bin:account_locked = true
```

so you can stick a `| grep whoever` on the end to see that user's attributes.

Comment: I like your idea. Anyway when I try with my system (Solaris 9), it doesnt work

Comment: ...when you try, what happens?

Comment: `bash-2.05# awk '/^[a-z]/ {user=$1} (NF>1) {$1=user$1; print}' aix_user.txt`    `admin = true
expires = 0101000070
account_locked = true
admin = true
expires = 0101000070
account_locked = true
admin = false
rlogin = false
sugroups = biscore
umask = 002
su = true
admin = false
rlogin = false
sugroups = biscore
umask = 002`  it's seem like just cut off User Name

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`. Example:

```
user=daemon
awk '{if(NF==1 && $1 == "'"$user"':") {flag=1;} else if(NF>1 && flag==1) {print} else {flag=0}}' output.txt
```

Output:

```
admin = true
expires = 0101000070
account_locked = true
```

---

In this form the `awk` script is more readable:

```
{
    if(NF==1 && $1 == "'"$user"':") {
        # set a flag when the desired user name appears
        flag = 1;
    } else if (NF > 1 && flag==1) {
        # print regular lines if flag is 1
        print;
    } else {
        # if another user name appears reset the flag
        flag = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ param1=root param2=registry perl -lane '
     if (/^(\w+)/) {
         $key = $1
     }
     else{
         $h->{$key}->{$F[0]} = $F[2]
     }
     END{print $h->{$ENV{"param1"}}->{$ENV{"param2"}}}
' file
```

Output:

```
files
```

Answer (score 1):

Really simple with awk:

```
$ awk '/^daemon:$/,/^$/' file
daemon:
    admin = true
    expires = 0101000070
    account_locked = true
```

Or if you want the user to come from a variable, you can do:

```
awk -v u="$daemon" '$0 == u,/^$/' file
```

Comment: @sputnick The expressions says: Print all the lines from the one where the line (`$0`) is equal to the variable `u` until the empty one `^$` (`^` is the start of the line, and `$` is the end of line)

Answer (score 1):

A `gnu awk` version:

```
awk '/^daemon/' RS="\n\n" files
daemon:
    admin = true
    expires = 0101000070
    account_locked = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know what the line numbers are:-

```
sed -n '9,12p' file > output_file
```

Otherwise the first answer is perfect.  The first answer is probably better anyway, because it is dynamic; you will get the entire daemon stanza, regardless of how many lines it occupies.  If you use line addresses and they change, then the script breaks.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$1 == "daemon:"' RS= input-file
```

When RS is the empty string, awk treats paragraphs as records, and your format is conveniently laid out so that the first field ($1) is the user name.